# Undefined behaviour in a simple version of the Boyer Moore algorithm

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, boyer-moore

I am trying to write the more simple version of the Boyer Moore algorithm without prefix-function. It has to print all positions of symbols which have been compared with a pattern. And locally it passes the tests, but it fails when I commit it to the gitlab. I can't spot undefined behaviour here. I have garbage at the end.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_PATTERN_LEN 16
#define BUF_SIZE 69
#define ALPH_SIZE 128

int read_str(int max_len, unsigned char *str_place) {
    int count_read = 0;
    for (int i = 0, ch; i < max_len; i++) {
        if ((ch = getchar()) == '\n') {
            str_place[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        str_place[i] = (char)ch;
        count_read++;
    }
    return count_read;
}

void calculate_shifts(const unsigned char *str, int len_str, int *badchar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPH_SIZE; i++)
        badchar[i] = len_str;
    for (int i = 0; i < len_str - 1; i++)
        badchar[str[i]] = len_str - 1 - i;
}

void search(const unsigned char *str, const unsigned char *patt, int len_patt, int len_str) {
    int badchar[ALPH_SIZE];
    calculate_shifts(patt, len_patt, badchar);
    int shift = 0;
    while (shift <= (len_str - len_patt)) {
        int j = len_patt - 1;
        for (; j >= 0 && patt[j] == str[shift + j]; j--)
            printf("%d ", shift + j + 1);
        if (j < 0) {
            shift += ((shift + len_patt) < len_str) ? badchar[patt[len_patt - 1]] : 1;
        } else {
            printf("%d ", shift + j + 1);
            int shift_addition = badchar[str[shift + j]];
            if ((shift_addition == len_patt) && (j < len_patt - 1) && (patt[len_patt - 1] == patt[0]))
                shift_addition--;
            shift += shift_addition;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned char str[BUF_SIZE + 1];
    unsigned char patt[MAX_PATTERN_LEN + 1];
    int len_patt = read_str(MAX_PATTERN_LEN + 1, patt);
    int len_str = read_str(BUF_SIZE + 1, str);
    if (!len_patt || !len_str)
        return 0;
    search(str, patt, len_patt, len_str);
    return 0;
}
```

the test:

```
example
this is simple example
```

the correct output:

```
7 14 13 12 11 10 20 22 21 20 19 18 17 16
```

the actual output:

```
7 14 13 12 11 10 20 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 28 ..
```

Comment: Why do you think this is undefined behavior?

Comment: @pts It passes tests locally, so that was the first idea. Could there be another reason?

Comment: Of course, @papacuma.  Your program could fail on inputs that differ in some significant way from all your local test inputs.

Comment: read_str fails to terminate max_len strings.

Comment: About undefined behavior: the output difference you have been observing can be explained by (1) undefined behavior, (2) different input, (3) different C compiler, libc etc., (4) others. My answer has revealed that (1) and (2) were indeed happening in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference (extra number 28 at the end of the output) can be caused by a missing newline character (`\n`) at the end of the last line of the input. I was able to reproduce both of your outputs (with and without the 28) locally.

```
$ gcc -g -O2 -W -Wall -o t t.c
$ printf 'example\nthis is simple example; \n' | ./t; echo
7 14 13 12 11 10 20 22 21 20 19 18 17 16
$ printf 'example\nthis is simple example; ' | ./t; echo
7 14 13 12 11 10 20 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 28
```

**TL;DR** Fix the bug in your code by changing `(ch = getchar()) == '\n'` to `(ch = getchar()) == EOF || ch == '\n'`, and changing `#define ALPH_SIZE 128` to `#define ALPH_SIZE 256`.

Maybe there is another bug, I haven't checked. If you encounter any other bugs, please ask it in a separate question on StackOverflow.

---

The rest of this answer explains how I diagnosed this bug.

[AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) `gcc -fsanitize=address`) reveals a memory access problem if the newline is missing:

```
$ gcc -g -O2 -W -Wall -fsanitize=address -o t t.c
$ printf 'example\nthis is simple example; \n' | ./t; echo
7 14 13 12 11 10 20 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 
$ printf 'example\nthis is simple example; ' | ./t; echo
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==19294==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7ffe25fbe264 (pc 0x563d6542b204 bp 0x7ffe25fbe264 sp 0x7ffe9a1bbc70 T0)
==19294==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x563d6542b203 in search /tmp/t.c:33
    #1 0x563d6542acb1 in main /tmp/t.c:54
    #2 0x7f617ff96c86 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21c86)
    #3 0x563d6542ad99 in _start (/tmp/t+0xd99)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /tmp/t.c:33 in search
==19294==ABORTING
```

Please note that I had to rerun it multiple times to trigger the AddressSanitizer error message.

Most of the time this is caused by a bug in your program, and often it's undefined behavior. The `in search /tmp/t.c:33` clause in the output of AddressSanitizer indicates where in your source code the bad read happens (i.e. line 33, function `search`).

I've added some extra `printf`s to your code to see what happens in line 33. The output is:

```
$ printf 'example\nthis is simple example; ' | ./t; echo
patt[6] == 101
str[6] == 115
patt[6] == 101
str[13] == 101
patt[5] == 108
str[12] == 108
patt[4] == 112
str[11] == 112
patt[3] == 109
str[10] == 109
patt[2] == 97
str[9] == 105
patt[6] == 101
str[19] == 112
patt[6] == 101
str[21] == 101
patt[5] == 108
str[20] == 108
patt[4] == 112
str[19] == 112
patt[3] == 109
str[18] == 109
patt[2] == 97
str[17] == 97
patt[1] == 120
str[16] == 120
patt[0] == 101
str[15] == 101
patt[6] == 101
str[27] == 255
patt[6] == 101
str[-369011759] == ??
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==19906==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7ffc6e5c0c71 (pc 0x5621e2363094 bp 0x0000ea0153d1 sp 0x7ffc845ab540 T0)
==19906==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x5621e2363093 in gett /tmp/t.c:33
    #1 0x5621e236349b in search /tmp/t.c:42
    #2 0x5621e2362e61 in main /tmp/t.c:63
    #3 0x7f7063ee8c86 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21c86)
    #4 0x5621e2362f49 in _start (/tmp/t+0xf49)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /tmp/t.c:33 in gett
==19906==ABORTING
```

The culprit is the last read access: `str[-369011759] == ??`, this indicates that `shift + j` becomes -369011759, which is obviously incorrect, because correct values are small nonnegative integers.

Please note that I had to rerun it multiple times to trigger the Address Sanitizer error message, and the number -369011759 was different each time.

It looks like `j` has a sane value of 6. To figure out the actual bug, the next step is checking where `shift` gets its large negative value.

At this point the output line `str[27] == 255` was suspicious to me. I checked your code whether it handles such large values in `str` correctly, and then I found a bug.

One way to fix this newfound bug is changing `ALPH_SIZE` from `128` to `256`. (I've verified that it makes the Address Sanitizer errors disappear.) Here is why. Line 39 contains the read  of `badchar[str[shift + j]]`. For that to be valid, we need `0 <= str[shift + j] && str[shift + j] < ALPH_SIZE`, because `ALPH_SIZE` is the size of the `badchar` array. However, the maximum value for `str[...]` is 255 (because it's an unsigned char), thus we need `ALPH_SIZE >= 256`.

Indeed, an out-of-bounds array access (read or write) is undefined behavior in C. To prove that this is actually happening, I've changed line 39 to

```
        printf("%d ", shift + j + 1); fprintf(stderr, "RBC %d == %d\n", shift + j, str[shift + j]);
```

, and I've also changed line 28 to use malloc:

```
    int *badchar = malloc(sizeof(int) * ALPH_SIZE);
```

, and I've also added `free(badchar)` later. With all that I've got:

```
$ gcc -g -O2 -W -Wall -include stdlib.h -fsanitize=address -o t t.c
$ printf 'example\nthis is simple example; \n' | ./t; echo
RBC 6 == 115
RBC 9 == 105
RBC 19 == 112
7 14 13 12 11 10 20 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 
$ printf 'example\nthis is simple example; ' | ./t; echo
RBC 6 == 115
RBC 9 == 105
RBC 19 == 112
RBC 27 == 255
=================================================================
==23463==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x61500000047c at pc 0x563915b3754a bp 0x7fff5f340710 sp 0x7fff5f340700
READ of size 4 at 0x61500000047c thread T0
    #0 0x563915b37549 in search /tmp/t.c:39
    #1 0x563915b36dc1 in main /tmp/t.c:54
    #2 0x7f1a63d6dc86 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21c86)
    #3 0x563915b36ea9 in _start (/tmp/t+0xea9)

Address 0x61500000047c is a wild pointer.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /tmp/t.c:39 in search
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c2a7fff8030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a7fff8040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c2a7fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a7fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a7fff8070: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x0c2a7fff8080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa[fa]
  0x0c2a7fff8090: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a7fff80a0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a7fff80b0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a7fff80c0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c2a7fff80d0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==23463==ABORTING
```

Indeed, the output of AddressSanitizer indicates the bug in line 39, and the output of the extra `fprintf` calls confirm that it's an out-of-bounds array access: reading of element 255 of the array `badchar`, which has only 128 elements.

How did we end up with `str[27] == 255` (thus reading `badchar[255]`)? That's easy: if there is no terminating `\n` at the end of the file when reading `str`, then `getchar()` returns EOF, which becomes 255 when assigned to an `unsigned char`. (The obvious fix, as above, is to stop at EOF instead, and change `ALPH_SIZE` to 256.)

Why hasn't AddressSanitizer reported the read of out-of-bounds array index problem (as a stack-buffer-overflow) in line 39 before  `badchar` was changed to use `malloc` (reported as heap-buffer-overflow)? I don't quite understand this yet. AddressSanitizer should be able to report stack-buffer-overflow reliably. Probably it depends on the GCC and Clang version, because changing the command `gcc` to `clang` made the stack-buffer-overflow error appear reliably. Probably upgrading to the latest GCC and Clang would help. Valgrind is not as reliable for detecting stack-buffer-overflow reads as AddressSanitizer.

Comment: That is impressive! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your `read_str()` function is flawed in two ways:

1. It does not recognize or handle end-of-file on the standard input.  This situation will not usually be encountered when the program's standard input is connected to a terminal, but it is entirely possible if the input is redirected from a regular file or a pipe (for example).  This will likely result in unwanted extra characters at the end of the string.
2. It will not add a string terminator to maximum-length input.

And those combine, because if `read_str()` does reach end-of-file then it will always behave as if it received a maximum-length input, and therefore fail to terminate it.

Failure to terminate will cause your program to exhibit undefined behavior elsewhere, but the source of the problem is `read_str()`.
My first recommendation would be to dump your `read_str()` altogether, and use standard [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead:

```
    fgets(str, BUF_SIZE + 1, stdin);
    len_str = strcspn(str, "\n");
    str[len_str] = '\0';  // trim a trailing newline, if any
```

But if you insist on your own `read_str()`, with parameters having the semantics implied by your code, then you need to correct the two problems described above.  Something like this, for example:

```
int read_str(int max_len, unsigned char *str_place) {
    int count_read = 0;
    int ch = EOF;
    for (int i = 0; i < max_len; i++) {
        ch = getchar();

        // break at newline OR EOF
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) {
            break;
        }

        str_place[i] = (char)ch;
        count_read++;
    }

    // If max_len characters were read without seeing end-of-line or end-of-file
    // then push the last back and adjust the number of characters accepted
    if (count_read >= max_len) {
        ungetc(ch, stdin);
        count_read--;
    }

    // Terminate the string after the last character accepted
    str_place[count_read] = '\0';
    return count_read;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- `ALPH_SIZE` is defined as `128`, which is not range of type `unsigned char`. You should use `(UCHAR_MAX+1)`, or 256 for 8-bit bytes, to allow the `badchar` array to handle characters in the string beyond `127` such as UTF-8 leading and continuation bytes or other non-ASCII contents. This is potential undefined behavior.
- you pass the length of the destination array to `read_str` for the argument `max_len` and you only null terminate this array if you read a newline before reaching `max_len` characters.  This is error prone: it might not cause a problem in the posted code, but is not recommended practice, especially as you are explicitly null terminating the array for shorter strings.
- the reading loop in `read_str` does not stop at end of file because you only test for `'\n'`. If the last line of input does not end with a newline, the loop will keep trying to read from `stdin`, receiving `EOF` from `getchar()` and storing `'\377'` (ie: `0xff` or `255`) into the array, later causing undefined behavior as the array `badchar` is too short to handle these byte values.